# Swift, Xcode - which view controller to use for horizontal and vertical swiping with dynamic content

Tags: swift, xcode, performance, uiviewcontroller, transition

I am working on an iPhone app and I was hoping someone could share their knowledge on which view controller would be best for functionality I would like to achieve.

I have two parameters x and y and I fetch text data from a web-service based on these two parameters. When a user performs a horizontal or a vertical swipe, I update x and y and fetch new data. This operation can be performed a very large number (thousands) of times in theory.

There are two things I am worried about here:

1. **Performance**. Since we can have a large number of swiping operations performed, there should be a method for deallocating data when not needed.
2. **Smooth transition**. I would like both the horizontal and vertical transition to be smooth, with the possibility to stop midway, as if transitioning between pages in a UIPageViewController.

I have done research on this and I have found these options so far:

1. **UIViewController with gesture recognizers**. This is what I have currently coded. I am using gesture recognizers to update data. For transitions I am using a method with CATransition. The problem with this method is that the transitions are not smooth and cannot be stopped midway. I guess I could spend more time on the transition method and make it work nicely, but that seems like a solution which is not elegant and horrible for maintenance, as Swift provides us with other view controllers which have this implemented. I am also not sure how the app would perform in this situation after hundreds of swipes.
2. **UIPageViewController**. I read that it is possible to do a vertical UIPageViewController inside a horizontal UIPageViewController, so that I could swipe in either direction to a new page. However, I am not sure if this is the right solution with dynamic content of possibly thousands of pages.
3. **UICollectionViewController**. As far as I understand, I could probably use UICollectionViewController for this as well.

Which view controller would have most suitable methods for this? I would like the solution to be elegant and easy to maintain further on. I don’t mind doing more research and figuring out how to do the coding, as long as I know which is the direction I should move in :)

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds as if your view controllers are doing too much. https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/lighter-view-controllers/

Comment: Might very well be so. Do you have a suggestion what implementation would be a better choice? :)

Comment: Oh, I just saw your link, sorry about that. The thing is that all the data is stored in a separate custom class, and data retrieval from a web-service is also done in that class. I only make an instance of that class in the view controller, so I believe that whatever view controller I would use, it would be quite light :)

Comment: That class sounds even worse.